# Is jQuery Tools Tooltips only about 90% reliable? (and how to fix it?)

Tags: tooltip, jquery-tools, jquery-tooltip

[jQuery Tools 1.2.5 Tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html) seems quite slick and fancy, but I added it to our development site, and it works 90% of the time.  Sometimes, the mouse hover over a tab and no tooltip shows up, and sometimes, the mouse leave the tab and the tooltip is still there.  (even on Firefox or Chrome)

Why can that be?

Also, on IE 7, the tooltip (which is HTML, not just text), will pop out a different `div`, not the one that contains the tooltip. (on IE 8 and 9, it works fine).  So I guess it works 90% of the time for me... and that's not good enough if it is not 99.9%.  So right now I am thinking either debugging it or use another tooltip, any suggestion?  Or is the standard [jQuery Plugin Tooltip](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip) the most reliable?  There are [30 of them](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/) on this page... that's just too much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [jQuery Tools 1.2.5](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html) Tooltip plugin is garbage in my opinion.  The tool tips often pop-up partially hidden and sometimes don't pop-up at all.  It doesn't matter what fancy features they add, if the basic tooltip functionality isn't reliable, the extra fanciness is useless.

[jQuery Plugin Tooltip](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip) is much more reliable, pops up every time, and in a good non-obscured position.

Comment: I was also thinking that maybe the officially supported jQuery version for it is 1.4.2, and I am using 1.5.2

Comment: @動靜能量, that could be a problem but I'm seeing issues on their demo site even.

Comment: Ok, at least a problem and fix I found is, if I use jQuery Tooltips on tabs -- so the main tab panel is a `<ul>`, and each tab is an `<li>`, and I use `<div>` to format each tooltip by HTML, then it will break on IE 7, but work on IE 8 and 9... oh well... the state of software... can be messy

Comment: the sample on their webpage is a simple 1 link, 1 tooltip... I tried it using 6 tabs, each having a tooltip, and on Firefox and Chrome, the tooltip sometimes not show up, and sometimes not go away.  It works "sometimes"...  I think it can irritate the users if the UI works "sometimes"

Comment: I just tried to download the jQuery Tools, and there were not even images in the zip. one has to grab them from elsewhere.
as to jQuery Plugin Tooltip, it has no benefit over the browser's native tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tried some more and it turns out that the prepackaged "full" version of jQuery 1.4.2 with jQuery Tools work well, about 99.9% of the time (for the Tooltips with sliding effect and HTML style tooltips).  (**Update**: I tried again today, and it is only 95% reliable... sigh...)

In http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html

```
<!-- jQuery Library + ALL jQuery Tools -->
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

I was using with our jQuery 1.5.1 and it worked only 90% of the time, and jQuery Tools wasn't updated for about half a year... (the stable version)...  so I guess it does have some compatibility issue with the newest jQuery.  I think at a point I was trying with 1.4.4 and it didn't work too well either as I recall.  But I suppose, with any library, try it with all the pre-packaged libraries it depends on.  Just that if another library our project uses depends on jQuery 1.5.1, then it can be harder to use both 1.4.2 and 1.5.1.