# What is a Javascript ToolTip library that can do HTML formatting, positioning, and is reliable?

Tags: tooltip, jquery-tooltip

What is a good Javascript tooltip library that can do HTML formatting and positioning?

jQuery tooltip plugin is said to be reliable but can it do HTML and positioning (such as bottom-center)?

jQuery Tools's Tooltip can do it except it is only about 90% reliable: [Is jQuery Tools Tooltips only about 90% reliable? (and how to fix it?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657842/is-jquery-tools-tooltips-only-about-90-reliable)

[This page list 30 of them](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/) but doesn't have information such as reliability.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used qTip, it couldn't hurt to check it out: [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)

I always use it with plain text and CSS, but there may be support for embedded HTML, but I couldn't say for sure.

EDIT: It looks like it supports HTML, [here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/content/youtube#) is an example putting a YouTube video in a tooltip.

EDIT 2: Here is a further example. Here the content is inline, but it can presumably be acquired through a DOM get:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Create the tooltips only on document load
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   // Match all link elements with href attributes within the content div
   $('#content a[href]').qtip(
   {
      content: '<p>Yo!</p>'
   });
});
</script>
```

EDIT 3: Looks like they have a version 2 almost out, and it looks slick! [LINK](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/)

Comment: when you are not sure whether it can do embedded HTML but give it as an answer, all the other people will stop looking at this question

Comment: @動靜能量: Maybe you could, you know, look into it and then upvote / downvote / comment accordingly. I was merely trying to help you, with what has worked for me in the past. Also, I looked into it for you, and edited my answer.

Comment: ok, looks like the documentation is here: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#content  but hopefully it is reliable...